# mysql problem: populate table from another table but referencing ID instead of name

Tags: mysql, join, subquery, union

I'm now trying to populate my 'testMatch' table (below) with data from my 'summary' table:

TESTMATCH TABLE

```
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field            | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| match_id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       | 
| match_date       | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| ground           | varchar(50)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       | 
| homeTeam         | varchar(100) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       | 
| awayTeam         | varchar(100) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       | 
| matchResult      | varchar(100) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       | 
| manOfMatch       | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| homeTeam_captain | int(10)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       | 
| homeTeam_keeper  | int(10)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       | 
| awayTeam_captain | int(10)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       | 
| awayTeam_keeper  | int(10)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       | 
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

There is no problem populating match_id -----> manOfMatch - it is 'homeTeam_captain', 'homeTeam_keeper', 'awayTeam_captain' and 'awayTeam_keeper' that i'm having problems bringing in.

SUMMARY TABLE

```
mysql> DESCRIBE SUMMARY;
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| matchID         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       | 
| Test            | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| matchDate       | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| Ground          | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| HomeTeam        | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| AwayTeam        | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| matchResult     | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| MarginRuns      | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| MarginWickets   | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| ManOfMatch      | varchar(40)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| HomeTeamCaptain | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| HomeTeamKeeper  | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| AwayTeamCaptain | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| AwayTeamKeeper  | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I need to somehow select the data from summary, get the corresponding player_id and input the player_id into my 'testMatch'. Player table below:

PLAYERS TABLE

```
mysql> describe players;
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| player_id      | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | 
| player_surname | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
| team           | varchar(100) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                | 
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

So to clarify, eg. I want to select homeTeam_captain data FROM summary table BUT not the name, I want the corresponding player_id instead.

I assume I need to use some sort of join/subqueries to get this done... i've tried finding the correct select query first to make sure i'm pulling out the right data, and I have been using the below code for testing (thanks to user Larry_Croft for helping me with this):

```
select matchID, player_id, player_surname, team from players p, summary s
where
s.hometeamcaptain = p.player_surname AND s.HomeTeam = p.team ORDER BY matchID;
```

But this correctly brings back 65 rows (65 matches) BUT i then tried it with:

```
select matchID, player_id, player_surname, team from players p, summary s
where
s.hometeamKEEPER = p.player_surname AND s.HomeTeam = p.team ORDER BY matchID;
```

But this brings back only 61 rows (should be 65) so i must have an error in the logic.

Once I get this select to work, i then need to somehow include it into my 'INSERT INTO.....SELECT statement to put all the data into 'testMatch' table.

I hope this makes sense and thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Well for me it looks that there is eitehr a hometeamKEEPER that has a null value or that the value of hometeamKEEPER is not in the players table.

Using the following query you should be able to find the hometownKEEPER that are not in the players table:

```
SELECT matchID, player_id, player_surname, team 
FROM players p 
     RIGHT JOIN summary s ON p.hometeamKEEPER = p.player_surname AND 
                             s.HomeTeam = p.team
ORDER BY matchID;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response but homeTeamkeeper definitely doesn't have any NULL values and all homeTeam/awayTeam_captain/keepers are in the player table.

Comment: Hi,

<code>select player_id
FROM   players p  right JOIN `summary` s  
ON s.awayteamcaptain = p.player_surname and s.awayteam = p.team;</code> works but when i try and use this query to insert into my 'testMatch' table I get the following error:
<code>
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'
</code>

I used to have homeTeam_captain as a foreign key to the player_id primary key... but in testMatch the same name (homeTeam_captain) can appear more than once (not unique) so I have removed the FK contraint but still get this error.

Thanks

Comment: INSERT INTO testMatch (homeTeam_captain)
select player_id
FROM   players p  right OUTER JOIN `summary` s  
ON s.hoemteamcaptain = p.player_surname and s.hometeam = p.team;

Comment: If you are using outer joins, you have to remember that unmatched entries are included in thre resultset, i.e. if you have a row in table a that has no key in table b then the outer join will still list both table in the result set, providing null for the values in the select that it cannot match. Therefore, I suggest that you look at your data using left and right joins to determine what goes wrong. For your insert query you should use an inner join to esure data consistency.

Comment: Hi, the above 'select' query brings me the correct data.  But as soon as I add it as a 'subquery' to my 'insert into testMatch' code, it brings back the error 'ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: This just meas that there are two entries on one side of the join for one on the right side, or even that there is a m:n in you resultset. You could use distict to throw out the duplicates.